# A clue for the geometry problem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

With respect to the picture $AB=DC  , \ B=10\alpha ,A_1=\alpha , c=2\alpha$ so need $\alpha$ I tried first to $A=A_1+A_2=\alpha +\beta$ so $$\beta =180-13\alpha$$ then draw a line $AF=AB$ as below or $DG=AB=DC$
[image]

but got nothing,
(seems like parallel lines, but I have no evidence to show this!) .

I get stuck on this after about 2 hours. Actually, I was far from geometry for years. Now I want a clue or a hint to take over and find a solution. Thanks in advance
Remark: I tried to write $sine/cosine  $ theorem ,but needs the relation for $5x $ arcs and become more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can  also use this figure. We have:

$AD_1||BC\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{AB}=\overset{\large\frown}{D_1C}=4\alpha$

$\overset{\large\frown}{D_1I}=\frac 12 \overset{\large\frown}{D_1C}=2\alpha$

$\overset{\large\frown}{CF}=2\alpha=\overset{\large\frown}{IC}$

$\overset{\large\frown}{AD_1C}=20\alpha$

$\overset{\large\frown}{AD_1C}-\overset{\large\frown}{IC}=20\alpha-2\alpha=18\alpha=180^o$

That is $\alpha=10^o$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: connect $B$ and $G$. $\triangle ABG$ is isosceles. Use this fact to write an equation involving $\measuredangle ABG$ (which is equal to $\measuredangle AGB$), and show that $\measuredangle ABG =\measuredangle AGB = 6\alpha$.

> We have $$\measuredangle BGD = 180^\circ - 2\alpha - \measuredangle AGB.$$ Thus, using the sum of the interior angles of $\triangle BGD$ we get \begin{eqnarray}\measuredangle BGD &=& 180^\circ - 4\alpha - (180^\circ-2\alpha-\measuredangle AGB)=\\&=&\measuredangle AGB-2\alpha.\end{eqnarray} Since $\measuredangle ABG + \measuredangle GBD = 10\alpha$, and $\measuredangle AGB = \measuredangle ABG$, we have $$2\measuredangle AGB - 2\alpha = 10\alpha.$$

So there is another isosceles triangle in the Figure. Which one? Can you reach your result from here?

> We get $\measuredangle GBD = \measuredangle GDB = 4\alpha$. Hence $BG \cong GD$. Therefore $\triangle ABG$ is equilateral and $\alpha = 10^\circ.$

Comment: thank you, you mean I draw $BG$ ? to see isosceles triangle

Comment: can you tell me why ABG
 is isosceles ?   this my problem ...thank you again ...but I can't understand what for ABG
 is isosceles

Comment: @Khosrotash observe first that $ADG$ is isosceles. Why?

Comment: This is the key point for me, I don't understand how isosceles is $ADG$ . I am thankful for your time and kindly hint. Can you elaborate a bit more hint for this key point?

Comment: @Khosrotash no problem at all. Use Exterior Angle Theorem, to show that $ADG$ is isosceles.

Answer (score 0):

(A nice another way) In your figure, one has in triangle $\triangle{ACB}$
$$\frac{AC}{\sin(10\alpha)}=\frac{AB}{\sin(2\alpha)}$$ and in triangle $\triangle{ACD}$
$$\frac{AC}{\sin(180-3\alpha)}=\frac{DC}{\sin(\alpha}$$ from which the equation in $\alpha$ $$\sin(10\alpha)=\frac{\sin(2\alpha)\sin(3\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)}$$
By periodicity, there are many solutions but we have the restriction $0\lt 13\alpha\lt180^{\circ}$ so $0\lt\alpha\lt13.8462^{\circ}$. Consequently we choose  the smallest positive solution which  is $\boxed{\alpha=10^{\circ}}$ and the angles of the triangles in question are $100, 20$ and $60$ degrees.

Comment: How do you solve the equation in the first place?

Comment: @dfnu There are a lot of solutions ($10^{\circ},45^{\circ},70^{\circ},90^{\circ},....$ and many negatives too. The equation is not of direct solution and you have to calculate as you can (plotting the curve is a way to find them)

Comment: I would hardly call it a way to solve this problem, then... A plot certainly does not give a numerical solution, for example..

Comment: @dfnu So, how can i get the four solutions i gave you ? Do you want more of them? I don't. How do you find out the only real solution of $x^5-4x^3+x^2+9x+1=0$?

Comment: That's precisely why OP gave up using trigonometric approach, as you can notice. And that's why I insist yours does not represent an alternative approach.